# WSO2 DSS - A way to expose single row / single column result as string

Tags: arrays, string, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I'm using WSO2 DSS and I'm interested in how to expose a single row/column result of a query as a string, and not as an array entry.

So for example if I have query: Select 'test' as t From dual;
It will return only one row with one column, so I don't want the result to be enclosed in  like below

```
<Entry>
      <t>test</t>
</Entry>
```

instead I would like to have just

```
<t>test</t>
```

as a response.
Is such a thing possible with dss? what type of output mapping needs to be used in such a case?

Answer (score 1):

In DSS you can add XSLT to extract the test from your response.
There is an field called XSLT Path in Result (output mapping) section. You can give the configuration registry path or governance registry path for that xslt to do that.